# Unable to release memory after playing a video

Tags: ios

I am unable to clear memory after playing a video in my iOS app. This is the code that I am using as of now.

```
mediaFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name" ofType:@"mp4"];
player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[player prepareToPlay];

[player play];
```

When I pop this controller after stoping the player, the memory doesnt get released. Am I doing something wrong or missing something here ?

Guidance needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're doing it in wrong way.
Instead of just init it, do init it with bundle name.

For example: 
mediaFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name" ofType:@"mp4"];
player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:@"YourBundleName"];
[player prepareToPlay];

[player play];

Try this.